# passing parameter of _id and updating SQLitedatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I'm trying to update an SQLite table using the row id as my where statement.  I'm getting the row _id from a row shown in a listview and passing to another activity with this statement:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) nurseTableAdapter.getItem((int)id);
            showAssignments.putExtra("Nurse", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
```

The receiving activity receives the parameter:

```
nurse = extras.getString("Nurse");
```

and passes it as a parameter to my DbCommunicator class:

```
updateAssignments.updateNurseAssignments(listItemsArray, nurse);
```

and my DbCommunicator class does this with it:

```
public void updateNurseAssignments(String[] choices, String nurseId) {
    // set parameter variables
    //int nurseIdToInt = Integer.parseInt(nurseId);
    //String strFilter = "_id=" + nurseIdToInt;
    //String where = "_id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(nurseId)};
    Log.i(TAG, "value of whereArgs is " + whereArgs[0]);

    // set content values
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_FIRST_ASSIGNMENT, choices[0]);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SECOND_ASSIGNMENT, choices[1]);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_THIRD_ASSIGNMENT, choices[2]);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_FOURTH_ASSIGNMENT, choices[3]);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_FIFTH_ASSIGNMENT, choices[4]);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_SIXTH_ASSIGNMENT,  choices[5]);

    // update database
    sqldb.update(NURSE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NURSE_ROWID + "= ?", whereArgs); 
}
```

I'm getting no errors, but the table is not updating.  I've only found one similar example in Stack Overflow, and have tried to incorporate some of that here, but still having problems.  Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: you put `Int`, but you use `getString`, did you check the value of `nurse`? is it the `_id` that you want?

Comment: I'm sure the value is the one I want, as I'm getting it directly from a listview I'd.  Its an Integer autoincrement.

Comment: what i meant is the `nurse` value that you received from your sender activity. is it the same with the sent value?

Comment: Yes, they are both null.  And I'm thinking that I don't want to use the long id value anyway, but instead I want to use getItemAtPosition(4), since that is the position of the _id value that I actually want to capture and send.  The code above was an attempt toward solving this problem, but I don't think it will work for what I'm trying to do, since I don't think the Long id value from the list activity would be the same as getItemAtPostion(4).  Does that make sense?

Comment: 'String nurse_id = parent.getItemAtPosition(4).toString();' passes the value of android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor @44ea4c98.  The same value is received

Comment: try `String nurse_id = parent.getItemAtPosition(4).getInt("_id").toString();`

Comment: I get an error with getInt underlined:  The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type object.  I'm not sure how to cast that.

Comment: use something like `((Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(4)).getInt("_id").toString();`

Comment: String nurse_id = ((Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(4)).getInt("_id").toString();  I'm having the problem:  The method getInt(int) in the type Cursor is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17158/discussion-between-aprian-and-deadeddie)